# Instagram error: Implicit authentication is disabled

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, instagram

When try to login to my app with **Instagram** account in **mobile Safari** I get **403** error: **Implicit authentication is disabled**.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

By security reasons Instagram disables OAuth 2.0 implicit authentication flow (**client-side authentication**) by default. If your app hasn't server side you should go to [Manage Clients](https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/) **Security** section and unset **Disable implicit OAuth** option. After saving all should work well.

[image: Example]

Comment: In my case it was already unchecked, but I had to explicitly check -> uncheck -> save (I guess it's a bug on their system)

Comment: as the site has changed now how can i disable implicit auth?

Comment: i cant see these options, how can i enable this.